# MVC - Multiple forms on the same page in partial view using dataannotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, data-annotations, partial-views

I have a form that occurs multiple times on multiple pages. I want to put this form in a partial view and use dataannotations to validate it.

This is what i got so far:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Form()
{
    return PartialView("_Form", new FormInput());
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(FormInput model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("_Form", model);
    }

    return PartialView("Form", new FormInput());
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("Form", "Forms")
</div>
<div>
    @Html.Action("Form", "Forms")    
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Forms"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

In this code the controller returns just the parital view and not the main view. What do i do wrong?

Is the only solution to solve this via ajax.beginform? I'd really like to use the standard post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the action method that returns your main view look like?

Comment: Hmm.. ok, well the controllers looks diffrent because the form appears on diffrent places on the page. Some return just a view and some a view with models.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a 'view' in your controller get method.

Then, on you view page render the partial views as:

```
@Html.Partial("_Form", new FormInput())
```